# setting the scope elements after the http call in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am new to AngularJs. I am calling a `http` get call to fetch a list of names and I want it as soon as the app loads. Hence I have written the logic to get the list of names in the `run` function on angularjs. I am using a custom `service` to fetch the names and calling the function inside the `run` method.

The code in the service method is as below:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('fetchData', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
    this.fetchNames = function() {
      $http.get('http://hostname:port/names').success(function (person) {
          $rootScope.names = person.names;
      });
  }
```

In my app.js, I have the code as below:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})

.run (function($rootScope, fetchData){
    //first make an ajax call and fetch all the applicatons for the given BU
    fetchData.fetchNames();
});
```

But by the `fetchNames` gets the names form the http call, the run method is already executed.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Since ajax request is an asynchronous call, The run function does not wait for the completion of request. **BTW, What is the problem?**

Comment: I want to use the attributes set to the rootScope in my `run` method but since this is asynchronous, I am not getting the value in the `run` function.

Comment: I am getting error in my `run` function

TypeError: fetchData.fetchNames is not a function

The code inside the run function is 

    fetchData.fetchNames();

Comment: Edited my answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In your service you can return the promise and then handle the success in your run function.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('fetchData', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
    this.fetchNames = function() {
      return $http.get('http://hostname:port/names');
  }
```

Now you can handle the success event in run.

```
.run (['$rootScope', 'fetchData', function($rootScope, fetchData){
    //first make an ajax call and fetch all the applicatons for the given BU
    fetchData.fetchNames().success(function (person) {
          $rootScope.names = person.names;
    );
}]);
```

Comment: Got it.Promises is the way since this is asynchronous call. But since I am using a custom directive to display the names and that the custom directive has an isolated scope, how to make the names available to the scope inside the directive. I mean, by the time, the names are set inside the `run` function, the directive would have been called. Whats the best way to make  the names available to the directive.

Comment: @Pradeep You can use two way binding and pass the names to directive. As soon as the names are updated by ajax call they will be reflected to the  directive variable to which you have bound the names.

Comment: can you please explain with an example on plnkr. That would be really cool if I can implement like the way you are telling.

Comment: @Pradeep You create a plnkr with your code & I'll improve it.